# How can I report the descripction in paypal from aplication android?

Tags: android, paypal

I am doing an application in android. I use PayPalPayment.class to connect with paypal, I want to report descripcion of her sold for it appear in more details.

Part of my code:

```
PayPalPayment thingToBuy = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("4.99"), "EUR", "Datos de contacto - "+pro.getTitulo());

Intent intent = new Intent(InfoProyecto.this, PaymentActivity.class);

intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT, CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT);
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID, CONFIG_CLIENT_ID);
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RECEIVER_EMAIL, CONFIG_RECEIVER_EMAIL);
// It's important to repeat the clientId here so that the SDK has it if Android restarts your 
// app midway through the payment UI flow.
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID, "APP-80W284485P519543T");
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYER_ID, "your-customer-id-in-your-system");
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);

startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);        
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT, CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT);
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID, CONFIG_CLIENT_ID);
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RECEIVER_EMAIL, CONFIG_RECEIVER_EMAIL);        
startService(intent);
```

outside  `onCreate()`

```
public void onBuyPressed(View pressed) {
    Double amount=Double.parseDouble(Amount.toString());

    PayPalPayment thingToBuy = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(amount)), "NOK","ITEM_S");        
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);        
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT, CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID, CONFIG_CLIENT_ID);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RECEIVER_EMAIL, CONFIG_RECEIVER_EMAIL);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);

    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}



public void onBuyPressed(View pressed) {
    Double amount=Double.parseDouble(Amount.toString());

    PayPalPayment thingToBuy = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(amount)), "NOK","ITEM_S");        
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);        
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT, CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID, CONFIG_CLIENT_ID);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RECEIVER_EMAIL, CONFIG_RECEIVER_EMAIL);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);

    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        PaymentConfirmation confirm = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
        if (confirm != null) {
            try {
                Log.i("paymentExample", confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));


                JSONObject json=confirm.toJSONObject();
                JSONObject payment=json.getJSONObject("payment");
                String product=payment.getString("short_description");
                String amount=payment.getString("amount").substring(0, 5);
                String currency_code=payment.getString("currency_code");
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Payment for "+product+" is done sucessfully. Amount of "+amount+" "+currency_code+" has been charged ..!!" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                tv.setText( getResources().getString(R.string.Payment_for)+product+""+getResources().getString(R.string.has_been_charge)+""+getResources().getString(R.string.Amount)+amount+
                        " "+currency_code+getResources().getString(R.string.has_been_charge));
                new ACtivate_POST().execute();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("paymentExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Log.i("paymentExample", "The user canceled.");
        Toast.makeText(this,"transaksjonen avbrutt.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_PAYMENT_INVALID) {
        Log.i("paymentExample", "An invalid payment was submitted. Please see the docs.");
        Toast.makeText(this,"En ugyldig betalingen ble sendt. Vennligst se docs.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. Now, how I could take the "pay key"

Comment: @CarlosSierraGarcia u will get a `Transaction ID`(Payment ID) after successful payment